# Checkbox Category and Subcategories using javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel

I have a list of category and subcategory(that is under category) like the image
what I want is when Client click on each category checkbox , it shows its subcategories

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAHBj.png]

Comment: Hi, add the relevant code so that others can see what you have tried so far and will be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this question I asked, It may help you (I answered by myself): [How to update variable on a foreach in blade laravel with js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64953946/8592712)

#### Edit :

Part of the answer that may help you to go through the problem, you have to load all categories and subcategories then play with JS and CSS to show what you want :

#### Blade code

```
@foreach($filatov as $d)
    <div class="col-md-6 folder" id="test{{$d['id_folder']}}" style="display: none">
        <div class="card mt-1">
            <div class="card-content py-50 px-1 folder-info">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-1">
                    <span><i class="feather icon-file-text font-medium-5"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h6 class="font-medium-2 mb-0">{{$d['fname']}}</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button value="{{$d['id_file']}}" type="button" class="download btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-success waves-effect waves-light"><i class="feather icon-download"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

#### JS code :

```
$(".getfolder").click(function(e){
   var id = $(this).val();
   var target = '.folder';
   $(target + '#test' + id).css('display', 'block');
   $(target).not('#test' + id).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27828447)

Comment: Ok i'll edit my answer to provide the correct information!

Comment: Thanks alot @therealwalim it was very usefull

Answer (score 0):

.
thanks to @therealwalim
I found the solution  :

```
<!-- ####################### Blade ######################3 -->

    <div class="content cat-content">
         <span class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span><p>مجموعه 
      ها </p><hr>   

         @foreach($categories as $item)
         @if($item->subcategories->count() > 0)

         <p><label><input  class="category cat{{$item->id}}" type="checkbox" 
         name="category[]" value="{{$item->id}}"  > {{$item->title}}</label></p>
          
         <div  id="subcat{{$item->id}}"  class="subcategory moveright"  
         style="display: none">
              @foreach($item->subcategories as $submenu)
            <p><label><input class="sub{{$item->id}}" type="checkbox" name="submenu[]" 
         value="{{$submenu->id}}" > {{$submenu->title}}</label></p>
            @endforeach
         </div>
           
         @else
              
                <p><label><input class="category" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{{$item->id}}"  > {{$item->title}}</label></p>
                

         @endif
         @endforeach
        
    </div>
```

just print all categories and their subcategories

```
<!-- ####################### Script ######################3 -->

<script>

$(".category").click(function(e){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var target = '.subcategory';
   
    if ($('input.cat'+ id).is(':checked')) {
        $(target + '#subcat' + id).css('display', 'block');
    }else
    {
         $(target + '#subcat' + id).css('display', 'none');
         $('.sub' + id).prop('checked', false)
    }

});
</script>
```